# Name of this font

Tags: font-identification, typefaces

[image: the southampton]

i want the name of font and possible link to get it from

Comment: Hi Raphael, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Comment: I found this funny, the image you posted has the name of the font in it. :)

Comment: yep, this is pretty funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "The Southamton" and it's available here: https://fontbundles.net/wnprh-co/2288-the-southamton